# ValueError:Error raised by inference API:Input validation error:inputs tokens+max_new_tokens must be<=2048.Give2562 input tokens and 100 max_new_token

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, huggingface, pinecone

```
index=Pinecone.from_documents(doc,embeddings,index_name=index_name)
retriever = index.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 1})
llm = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id="google/flan-t5-xxl", model_kwargs={"max_length":512})
from langchain.chains.qa_with_sources.retrieval import RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain
qa_chain = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_chain_type(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=retriever, return_source_documents=True) 
result = qa_chain({"question": "What is Recurrent Neural Network?"})
```

I am using Pinecone vector store , hugging face model flan-t5-xxl and RetrievalQA with sourceschain to get answer with sources of answer I have used 10 research papers as input documents but I keep getting this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[34], line 1
----> 1 result = qa_chain({"question": "What is Recurrent Neural Network?"})

File e:\Interview\Complete-Langchain-Tutorials\LLM Generic APP\LLM_Project\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:316, in Chain.__call__(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks, tags, metadata, run_name, include_run_info)
    314 except BaseException as e:
    315     run_manager.on_chain_error(e)
--> 316     raise e
    317 run_manager.on_chain_end(outputs)
    318 final_outputs: Dict[str, Any] = self.prep_outputs(
    319     inputs, outputs, return_only_outputs
    320 )

File e:\Interview\Complete-Langchain-Tutorials\LLM Generic APP\LLM_Project\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:310, in Chain.__call__(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks, tags, metadata, run_name, include_run_info)
    303 run_manager = callback_manager.on_chain_start(
    304     dumpd(self),
    305     inputs,
    306     name=run_name,
    307 )
    308 try:
    309     outputs = (
--> 310         self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
    311         if new_arg_supported
    312         else self._call(inputs)
...
    114 if self.client.task == "text-generation":
    115     # Text generation return includes the starter text.
    116     text = response[0]["generated_text"][len(prompt) :]

ValueError: Error raised by inference API: Input validation error: `inputs` tokens + `max_new_tokens` must be <= 2048. Given: 2562 `inputs` tokens and 100 `max_new_tokens`
```

I was expecting a simple answer with the sources

Comment: try to use CSVLoader / Dataframe loader to load the file

Comment: But all files are in pdf form

Comment: could you add a example to the `inputs` in `self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)`

Comment: I don't use any of the libraries but the error message tells you that your documents contain too much text (i.e. too many tokens).